# Different orders.refund with purchases.subscriptions.refund for subscription refund on GooglePlay IAP

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api

Per doc [purchases.subscriptions.refund](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/refund)

> Refunds a user's subscription purchase, but the subscription remains valid until its expiration time and it will continue to recur.

and doc [orders.refund](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/orders/refund)

> orders.refund a user's subscription or in-app purchase order

Both of them could be used to do subscription refund on GooglePlay IAP. What the different between them?